# How do I get my div container to stay in place regardless of the changes happening in other containers?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

[image]

[image]

So, the div container which I want to stay in place is the `dot-container` , as you can see, as the paragraphs get longer, the dots move down and adjust, I want them to stay in place no matter the size of the paragraph. How can I achieve this?

I've tried a few things and no luck, like setting a height to the dot-container and setting top and bottom margins, as well as adding a wrapper container. Please help, thanks in advance!!

```
<section id="reviews">
            <div class="review-container">
                <img src="images/testimonial-image.jpg" alt="people browsing through a laptop and smiling" class="review-img">
                <div class="testimonials">
                    <h2 class="review-heading">What People Say</h2>

                    <!--                    first testimony-->
                    <div id="tst1">
                        <p class="review-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
                        <div class="review-photo">
                            <img src="images/tst-image1.jpg" class="test-img">
                            <h4 class="tst-name">Austin</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--                    second testimony-->
                    <div id="tst2">
                        <p class="review-paragraph">Donec pretium tristique elit eget sodales. Pellentesque posuere, nunc id interdum venenatis, leo odio cursus sapien, ac malesuada nisl libero eget urna.</p>
                        <div class="review-photo">
                            <img src="images/tst-image2.jpg" class="test-img">
                            <h4 class="tst-name">Sofia</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--                    third testimony -->
                    <div id="tst3">
                        <p class="review-paragraph">Vestibulum tempor facilisis efficitur. Sed nec nisi sit amet nibh pellentesque elementum. In viverra ipsum ornare sapien rhoncus ullamcorper.</p>
                        <div class="review-photo">
                            <img src="images/tst-image3.jpg" class="test-img">
                            <h4 class="tst-name">Monica</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="dot-container">
                        <div class="dot" onclick="firstTst();"></div>
                        <div class="dot" onclick="secondTst();"></div>
                        <div class="dot" onclick="thirdTst();"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
```

Comment: Could you provide a working code snippet ? Also You can try `overflow:auto`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the images are all equal height - then I'd give the outer class a relative position, then you can position the dot container absolute in relation to its parent:

```css
.testimonials {
    position: relative;
 }
 
 .dot-container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    // .. other positioning stuff
 }
```